How Place a Market order on MEXC API KEY?
I am sending in just a take profit price variable. Do I need to send in Stop Loss as well?
def post_place(symbol, price, vol, side, type, openType, leverage=None, positionId=None, externalOid=None, 
               stopLossPrice=None, takeProfitPrice=None, positionMode=None, reduceOnlt=None):
    """Place new order"""
    method = 'POST'
    path = '/api/v1/private/order/submit'
    url = '{}{}'.format(BASE_URL, path)
    
    print(f"Preparing to place trade with the following details:\n"
          f"Symbol: {symbol}, Price: {price}, Volume: {vol}, Side: {side}, Type: {type}, OpenType: {openType}, "
          f"Leverage: {leverage}, PositionId: {positionId}, ExternalOid: {externalOid}, "
          f"TakeProfitPrice: {takeProfitPrice}, StopLossPrice: {stopLossPrice}, PositionMode: {positionMode}, ReduceOnly: {reduceOnlt}")

    data_original = {
        'symbol': symbol,
        'price': price,
        'vol': vol,
        'side': side,
        'type': type,
        'openType': openType
    }
    
    if leverage:
        data_original.update({"leverage": leverage})
    if positionId:
        data_original.update({"positionId": positionId})
    if externalOid:
        data_original.update({"externalOid": externalOid})
    if takeProfitPrice:
        data_original.update({"takeProfitPrice": takeProfitPrice})
    if positionMode:
        data_original.update({"positionMode": positionMode})
    if reduceOnlt:
        data_original.update({"reduceOnlt": reduceOnlt})

    data = json.dumps(data_original)
    print(f"Data to be sent: {data}")

    params = _sign_v1(sign_params=data)
    headers = {
        "ApiKey": API_KEY,
        "Request-Time": str(_get_server_time()),
        "Signature": params,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    print(f"Headers: {headers}")

    try:
        response = requests.request(method, url, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=10)
        print(f"Response received: Status Code: {response.status_code}, Response Text: {response.text}")
        response_json = response.json()
        print(f"Response JSON: {response_json}")
        return response_json
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print(f"Connection error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return {"error": "connection_error"}
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("Error: The request timed out.")
        return {"error": "timeout"}
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error occurred during the API request: {str(e)}")
        return {"error": str(e)}

Am trying to send an order to MEXC to place an order on MEXC. The code freezes upon sending to API and I am not sure where the problem is. I don't think the issue is with my code, am just not sure if am not inputting all the values I am supposed to such as the Stop Loss.

I think the path should be
path = '/api/v3/order'

